# Palantir foundry code repository "shortcuts" not behaving as expected

Tags: refactoring, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, python-language-server

In Palantir Foundry's Code Repository application there are several commands available under the command palette menu, that can be accessed by pressing F1. However these commands:

- are undocumented, as far as I can tell
- don't really work as expected, even though they appear similar in name and function to VSCode commands.

For example: the "rename symbol" command provides a text field when invoked while the cursor is on a variable/function name. However when changing the name and pressing "return":

- expected: all subsequent instances of the symbol are renamed
- actual: nothing happens. No error message is given.

Pretty much the same behaviour for all other "refactoring-oriented" commands.

I am wondering wether there is something wrong with our instance -- and if so, should i report it -- or if I am missing something obvious (such as perhaps the need to change some setting, import some library, or something that's written in the docs)

Comment: good find, however for renaming, you can use ctrl + F2 and then when you type it will change everywhere. and for F2 rename option, there is a js error as it cannot detect the workspace and causes an error, you can see it in console of your browser